# RPA Automation Anywhere - Open Browser vs REST Web Service - The response for this request has timed out

Tags: rest, http-proxy, rpa, automationanywhere

Why would a browser on my VDI be able access a specific URL whereas a `REST Web Service` Command would return an error? The error is: **The response for this request has timed out** .

All the environment is trial, so the whole thing is running in the same machine. This makes me suppose it is not a firewall problem.

My first guess would be Proxy. Is there a way to configure proxy when running my bot on my development machine?

[image: The response for this request has timed out picture]

Once I try to configure the proxy, it complains the port (8080) is being used by another process. I don't understand why would it complain since the proxy serve is a different one. The second picture shows the error.

[image: Proxy settings fails]

Comment: What error will the REST request return?

Comment: @marek I improved the questions content with the info

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the timeout value for the REST command.

Add  tag in the AA.Settings.xml 
**AA.Settings.xml** can be found under the application path, you can find it in the settings.

```
<restwebservice> 
<timeout>10000</timeout> 
</restwebservice>
```

**Note:** Timeout is in milliseconds.